# Finding birth certificate of someone born on a military base in Germany

Tags: records, military-records, birth-records, 20th-century

I am looking for a relative, probably born on a military base in Germany around 1954. I found her and her mother on a passenger list coming from Germany back into a port in NY in 1954. The mother was born in Louisiana and the daughter was born in Germany. No ages are listed on the document. How do I locate a birth certificate if she is a US citizen but born in Germany? She is deceased and so is her mother and all descendants are deceased.

Comment: You wrote, "She is deceased and so is her mother ..." Have you located these individuals in the social security death index (which might provide a clue about when each was born)?

Comment: Don't hesitate to specify names and places in the question, the more information you provide the more we as a community can assist you.

Answer (score 5):

The U.S. State Department handles the acquisition of records pertaining to children born overseas on Military installations.

The links below should provide you with a map, and other resources to narrow down your search. The Base installation (place name) and the person(s) name will make your search more easily obtainable.

[Military.com: Military installations map, Germany](http://benefits.military.com/misc/installations/Browse_Map.jsp?country=GERMANY)

[U.S. Department of State, Office of the Historian](http://history.state.gov/)